# How to display a next set of options in UIMenuController

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller

If you highlight a word on iOS, Apple presents a "Replace..." option in a UIMenuController. Upon tapping it, the menu controller changes its set of options to the replacement words:

[image]

How can I achieve this same behavior of updating the items after an option is chosen?

---

I tried calling UIMenuController.[`update()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/1622815-update) but after selecting the first option, the menu disappears. I have to tap again to show the menu.

[image]

I already know how to customize the menu items and add my own.

I can't figure out how to make the menu show up after an option is selected though. I tried doing the following:

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {

  /// called once on viewDidLoad
  func initializeMenuItems() {
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [
      UIMenuItem(title: "Thesaurus...", action: #selector(thesaurusTapped)),
    ]
  }

  @objc
  private func thesaurusTapped(_ sender: UIMenuController) {
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [
      UIMenuItem(title: "Experiment", action: #selector(replacementTapped)),
      UIMenuItem(title: "Trial", action: #selector(replacementTapped)),
      UIMenuItem(title: "Inspection", action: #selector(replacementTapped)),
    ]

    UIMenuController.shared.update()
  }

  @objc
  private func replacementTapped(_ sender: UIMenuController) {
    // TODO: Display the option the user chose
  }

  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return action == #selector(replacementTapped) || action == #selector(thesaurusTapped)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `update`, call `setMenuVisible(:,animated)`:

```
UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

This will produce the effect you're looking for:

[image]